# Unable to read data from excel file based on the columns in SQL Server table

Tags: c#, ssis

I need to load data from multiple excel files to single table in sql server. But, I may get different headers in different files. Also, no of columns in excel will be less when compared to table. So, I'm trying to take columns from excel files and comparing against system table in database to get the corresponding column name. I'm using this inside a script task in SSIS package. Please see the code and sample data given below. Getting an error while doing column mapping.

```
Name    EmpId   Salary
Anna    PD200   200
Julie   PD300   300

Name    EmpId   Sal
Maria   PD400   400
Treeza  PD500   500


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testLoad]
(
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [EmpId] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Salary] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)

public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here

            string filepath = Dts.Variables["User::var_File_Path"].Value.ToString();
            string tablename = Dts.Variables["User::var_Tbl_Name"].Value.ToString();
            string filename = Dts.Variables["User::var_File_Name"].Value.ToString();
            string tbl = tablename.Replace("[", "");
            tbl = tbl.Replace("]", "");
            tbl = tbl.Replace("dbo.", "");

            SqlConnection sqlconnection = new SqlConnection();
            sqlconnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["ADOAUDIT"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction));

            string ConStr;
            string HDR;
            HDR = "YES";
            ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + filepath + "; Extended Properties=\"EXCEL 12.0 XML; HDR="+HDR+"\";";
            OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);
            cnn.Open();
            DataTable dtSheet = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);


            string sheetname = "";
            string ExcelColumn = "";
            string SqlColumn = "";
            string SqlColumns = "";
            string ExcelCol = "";
            string query = "";
            string querycol = "";

            foreach (DataRow drSheet in dtSheet.Rows)
            {
                sheetname = drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand(" top 1  * from [" + sheetname + "]", cnn);
                OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adp.Fill(dt);
                cnn.Close();

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    ExcelCol = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                    ExcelCol = ExcelCol.Substring(0, 5);

                    querycol = "select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS " +
                        "where TABLE_NAME = '" + tbl + "' " +
                        "and COLUMN_NAME like '" + ExcelCol + "%'";
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(querycol, sqlconnection);
                    SqlColumn = (string)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SqlColumn))
                    {
                        SqlColumns = SqlColumns + "'" + SqlColumn + "',";
                        ExcelColumn = ExcelColumn + "'" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "',";
                    }
                }

                SqlColumns = SqlColumns.TrimEnd(',');
                ExcelColumn = ExcelColumn.TrimEnd(',');
                query = "select " + ExcelColumn + " from [" + sheetname + "]";

                OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);
                conn1.Open();
                OleDbCommand oconn1 = new OleDbCommand(query, conn1);
                OleDbDataAdapter adp1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn1);
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                adp1.Fill(dt1);
                conn1.Close();

                //Load Data from DataTable to SQL Server Table.
                using (SqlBulkCopy BC = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlconnection))
                {
                    BC.DestinationTableName = tablename;
                    foreach (var column in dt1.Columns)
                    {
                        BC.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), SqlColumns.ToString());
                    }

                    BC.WriteToServer(dt);
                }
                sqlconnection.Close();
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration
        /// <summary>
        /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
        /// result of the script.
        /// 
        /// This code was generated automatically.
        /// </summary>
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
```

Thank You
Julie

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this is going to be a pain to setup and maintain.  Here is a way to merge 2 Excel files into 1.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();

            app.Visible = true;
            app.Workbooks.Add("");
            app.Workbooks.Add(@"C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\excel_files\Book1.xlsx");
            app.Workbooks.Add(@"C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\excel_files\Book2.xlsx");


            for (int i = 2; i <= app.Workbooks.Count; i++)
            {
                int count = app.Workbooks[i].Worksheets.Count;

                app.Workbooks[i].Activate();
                for (int j = 1; j <= count; j++)
                {
                    Excel._Worksheet ws = (Excel._Worksheet)app.Workbooks[i].Worksheets[j];
                    ws.Select(Type.Missing);
                    ws.Cells.Select();

                    Excel.Range sel = (Excel.Range)app.Selection;
                    sel.Copy(Type.Missing);

                    Excel._Worksheet sheet = (Excel._Worksheet)app.Workbooks[1].Worksheets.Add(
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing
                    );

                    sheet.Paste(Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I were you, I would not use C# for this kind of thing.  I think you are better off using VBA, to push the date from each Excel file into SQL Server.  Here are some options for you to consider.

https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm#Introduction

Or, used SQL to go grab the data out of the excel files and load everything into SQL Server.

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(
    'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;Database=T:\temp\Test.xlsx',
    'select * from [sheet1$]')
```

Or, even consider using a 3rd party resource to merge all excel files into 1, and then load that into SQL Server.  Here is an example of what I'm talking about.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

[image]